# Download file program using php on unix box

Tags: php, unix

I have created a beginner program to forcefully download file from unix box to windows through browser, it is not throwing any error but shows nothing on browser just a blank page.

PHP version- 5.2.13
Apache-2.0
Unix Box- HP-UX 11.11 (old version latest is 11.31)
local PC- windows XP Prof.
Browser- IE 7, Mozilla.

Below is my code (this code resides on unix box):

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $file = '/opt/hpws/apache/htdocs/barn/file2';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You cannot force the user's browser to do anything.

Comment: Could anyone pls look into this and tell me what am I missing here, first I thought that my IE might have compatibility issue but then I tried on Mozilla and it's still not working. No errors , just when I visit on that link through browser it loads to blank page nothing else. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick note: the single quotes in "header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file');" prevent $file from being expanded. Also, you probably want output buffering to be *off*.

Comment: ...and just to be sure, outside the if(), place a `die("The file was not found");`. It costs little and is sometimes useful.

Comment: @theartist33 Try without the path. I.e. `$file = 'file.txt';` as an example if file resides inside the same folder as your code.

Comment: @theartist33 And this line was not properly formatted `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file');` - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line had quotation marks missing:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file');
```

and in trying to use that line of code, the browser would prompt to save the file as `$file`.

The line of code should read as:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
```

The following (tested with a binary file) with file inside the same folder as executed code.

**NOTE**: You could use `header("Content-Type: application/text");` if it's an ASCII file.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $file = 'file.zip';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');

        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Andy- By force downloading I meant that once you visit link/site it will prompt or open a save dialogue box which prompt to download that $file on your local PC.It can be done, possible.

Comment: @lserni- By disabling/off output buffer will give warnings so need to set output buffer.Already tested long back.

Comment: ...what warnings? The system doesn't warn you for the fun of it. Was there some other output sent before the file?

Comment: @Fred-ii- with or without path if file resides in same folder as code then it doesn't matter actually, the main problem was I guess as you pointed the quotation mark was missing, although I tried with basename($file) earlier but then too I was missing quotation mark. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It is working now, thanks for resolving Fred and thanks all for your time.Appreciate it.

Comment: @Fred-ii and lserni , could you pls refer to below link for same kind of problem of mine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693915/download-file-program-using-php-on-hp-ux-box/18695050#18695050

Comment: @theartist33 See my comment in your new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693915/download-file-program-using-php-on-hp-ux-box/18695050#comment27547504_18693915

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's add some checks and debugging.

```
<?php

    $file = '/opt/hpws/apache/htdocs/barn/file2';

    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        die("The file does not exist");
    }
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        die("Not a file"); // Worry about symlinks later
    }
    if (!is_readable($file)) {
        die("The file is not readable");
    }

    die("DEBUG: Okay, will send the file -- remove this line and retry");

    $name = basename($file); // Or anything else

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$name}\"");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit();
?>
```

If this does not work, it should *at least* tell you why. Also, on the first run, the one when it will still not download the file but only tell you that it will, check that the page *does not contain anything else except that one line*. Otherwise, you're setting yourself up for a fall; if not this once, as soon as you have to send a file larger than your output buffers, or too many files for your system memory.

Comment: yes it is working now lserni, real problem was synatx in "content-disposition" but I wonder why it did not throw any error. thanks anyways  I tried your code it is working as well.