# Download file program using PHP on HP-UX box

Tags: php, html, forms, unix

I'm having trouble modifying my PHP program. Originally, the program would download a particular file from a Unix box, which worked fine. Now I've modified it a little so the user can enter a file name to download.

Now it's not working, and I'm not sure why. It doesn't throw any errors that I can see; the page simply returns blank.

```
PHP version - 5.2.13
Apache - 2.0
Unix Box - HP-UX 11.11 (old version; latest is 11.31)
local PC - Windows XP Pro
Browser - IE 7, Mozilla
```

Code:

```
       <html>

      <body>


      <?php

      ob_start();
      if(isset($_POST['name']))

       {

       $file = $_POST['name'];
      echo "file is  $file" ;
     if(!file_exists($file))

       {

     die("file not found: " );

     }


       $name = basename($file);
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');

          header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
           header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
          header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
             ob_clean();
         readfile($file);
            exit;

             }

           else

              {
             echo " <form action='download1.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>


       <b> Enter the file name: </b><input type='text' name='name'>
        <br> <br>
        <button type='submit'> Upload </button>

     </form>";
          }
      ?>
         </body>

         </html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have code before the download headers ? The headers are already sent on the first html output, thus the download won't work when you send subsequent headers

Comment: You need to put ob_start() at the begining. Before html

Comment: I think the problem may be inside `download1.php`. Can you post your code for that? Your above code does show `Enter the file name:` with an `Upload` button, however what I think you need to have instead of `input type='text' name='name'>` is `input type='file' name='name'>`. That will automatically create a "browse" button where once people click on it, will open a box where they an choose a file from their computer.

Comment: Thanks Fred -ii- for coming up here, you misunderstood my current code..code is to download the file from unix to local pc..now as you say if to get a browse button, that will act as uploading the file..what I am doing is just create atext box(input type='text') so as one can enter the file name(which is the same resides on unix) and therefore once you click on submit button(as i created) wil result in downloading that file from unix to local PC.Also the whole code is download1.php (it's not like another php program am including)

Comment: also, my code which am having problem is topmost on this page(for downloading typically any general file), the one I posted below is working fine(it is for downloading specific file)

Comment: "Upload" in my code is arbitrary..could be anything like "submit file name" or anything

Comment: @theartist33 Ah OK, I understand what you want to do now. So someone would need to know the "exact" file name in order to download it. If for instance you have a file called `File.zip` and `file.zip`, those would be treated as two different filenames because the first starts with an uppercase letter.

Comment: yes you are right Fred-ii-..you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved, I just removed   tags from my code and it worked fine..It seems that output was buffering and either it was not sent to browser or it could not come out of buffer to display or to function as per my understanding..thanks for your time guys...

Answer (score 0):

As Vlad says you are outputting content before caling headers - therefore your code *is throwing errors* hence your first task is to resolve the problem that you can't se the errors it is throwing.

Your code checks if the file exists - but not if it is readable.

The next problem is that, even if it did find readable content it would be returning it embedded within HTML tags.

Comment: @jcubic--setting ob_start() before html tag wil display 'ob_start' on the page, so it is meaning less.

Comment: @Vlad- Even though I have code before headers, ob_start() will buffer the output. Since I have used code before sending headers that's why I have used ob_start() which nullify the effect.I don't think this is the prob.

Comment: @symcbean-- I didnt say my code is throwing error, instead it is not throwing any error at all. just displaying blank page.

Comment: Below is my code which was original and I created to download particular file and it is working correctly.

Comment: @theartist33: "However it is not throwing any error" - yes it is throwing errors

Comment: @symcbean--you are right it must be throwing error but it cud not be displayed that was the main error and the root cause of my prob..check my answer I got it working now..thanks anyways for your time and efforts

Answer (score 0):

Below is my original code working fine:

```
<?php

$file = '/opt/hpws/apache/htdocs/barn/file2';

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    die("The file does not exist");
}
if (!is_file($file)) {
    die("Not a file"); // Worry about symlinks later
}
if (!is_readable($file)) {
    die("The file is not readable");
}

//    die("DEBUG: Okay, will send the file -- remove this line and retry");

$name = basename($file); // Or anything else

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$name}\"");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Fred -ii- for coming up here, you misunderstood my current code..code is to download the file from unix to local pc..now as you say if to get a browse button, that will act as uploading the file..what I am doing is just create atext box(input type='text') so as one can enter the file name(which is the same resides on unix) and therefore once you click on submit button(as i created) wil result in downloading that file from unix to local PC.Also the whole code is download1.php (it's not like another php program am including)

Comment: You're welcome. See my answer, it works and will echo `$file <= (filename asked) does not exist` if file does not exist. (tested).

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

To run it as one file and using `action=''`  to accomplish this, try the following:

```
<?php
ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {

$file = $_POST['name'];
echo "file is  $file" ;
if (file_exists($file)) {

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
// header("Content-Type: application/text");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

ob_clean();

readfile($file);
exit;
}
}

/*
if (!file_exists($file)) { 

echo "<br>";
echo "$file does not exist.";
}
*/
?>

<form action='' method='post'>
<b> Enter the file name: </b><input type='text' name='name'>
<br> <br>
<button type='submit'> Upload </button>
</form>
```

---

### Original answer

Try it this way instead with two seperate files. (tested)

**Note:** File must reside inside the same folder as executed code and must be the exact file name.

**I.e.:** `File.zip` and `file.zip` would be treated as two different filenames because the first starts with an uppercase letter.

### HTML form

```
<form action='download_file.php' method='post'>
<b> Enter the file name: </b><input type='text' name='name'>
<br> <br>
<button type='submit'> Upload </button>
</form>
```

**Note:**  `enctype='multipart/form-data'` is not necessary.

### PHP hander (download_file.php)

```
<?php
ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {

$file = $_POST['name'];
echo "file is  $file" ;
if (file_exists($file)) {

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
// header("Content-Type: application/text");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

ob_clean();

readfile($file);
exit;
}
}

if (!file_exists($file)) { 

echo "<br>";
echo "$file does not exist.";
}
?>
```

Comment: ok..i will try it and probably it will work but you are separating html and php in two different codes as it seems, i wanted to mix this in single code(download1.php)..Also, I never had problem with my code when I test on my laptio but when I wrote it on hp-ux box I encountered with problem, I will only let you know tomorrow once I reach office as I have got my HP UX box there.

Comment: I will re-test in one file and edit my answer accordingly, cheers.

Comment: I edited my answer with both as one file or two files. Both work.

Comment: both work for me too....when i modified by myself on my laptop..(my own code) but not able to deploy on unic box in office

Comment: Can I find you on facebook? it's easy to chat there

Comment: Oh, I see. Well then it's gotta be a setting in your `php.ini` or other config file. You may have to set your action something like this `action="localhost/download.php"` or something like that. I'm not much of a Unix/Unic/Linux guy to tell you the truth.

Comment: no problem in php.ini or 'action' as when I wrote and tested to download specific file code it worked on unix box..this is what not working..also i am going to post the one which is correctly working on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Below is the one working fine on my laptop but not on unix box..

```
enter code here

        <!DOCTYPE html>

           <html>

            <body>




             <?php

     if(isset($_POST["name"]))
        {
          ob_start();



      $file = $_POST["name"];
     if(!file_exists($file))

     {
       echo "$file <br>";
            die( "your file does not exist:");

         }


         elseif (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');

        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
         header('Expires: 0');
           header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
         header('Pragma: public');
         header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

         readfile($file);
        exit;
        }

         }

    else
          {

       echo "<form action='download1.php' method='POST' enctype='html/form-data'>

        Enter your file name : <input type='text' name='name' >
   <br>
    <br>
     <button type='submit'>Submit</button>

  </form>";
    }
       ?>



       </body> 

       </html>
```